# How do I get newest version of adobe flashplayer?

Tags: flash

How do I get newest version of adobe flashplayer?

I don't have a application to open **APT** links

Comment: sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin

Comment: It works for everyone else. You did not give any information on your system. Is it Windows 10? ;-)

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop

Comment: Go to: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way is to go to Ubuntu Software Center and install Flash Player plugin.